# How to use "?main=" in HTML / PHP

Tags: php, html, href, web-development-server

I am trying to reference a file from a subdirectory of my root folder in a way that only the "main" changes.

I have this pice of code in my home.php file:

```
<div id="main" class="main">
        <?php require $_GET['main'] . ".php"; ?>
    </div>
```

All the navigation buttons should change the "main" to certain files in various folders under the folder which contains home.php.

The below code snippet works perfectly if the file I am referencing is in the same folder as my working file:

```
<a href="?main=dashboard.php">Dashboard 1</a>
```

What I want to do is (I imagine) like this:

```
<a href="?main=folder/dashboard.php"> Dashboard 1</a>
```

where the file I am referencing is in a different folder.

Also, if I reference the file in question with

```
<a href="folder/dashboard.php"> Dashboard 1</a>
```

the file loads, but it does not target the "main" like it should with `?main=`

I tried myriad ways that I read about / though would work, but nothing did so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First: **don't do that without validation**. Because any path could be injected. Second: You need to URL encode the slash in the path of `?main=folder/dashboard.php`.

Comment: in all cases `?main=dashboard.php`, would end up doing `require 'dashboard.php.php';`

Comment: I tried url encoding, but it does not seem to work (probably my fault). Could you please provide me with a working example? @MarkusZeller

Comment: Yeah, because you supply `.php` in the URL and add in the code as well.

Comment: Okay, url encoding plus removing the .php worked. Many thanks to both of you!

Comment: _Just a note:_ I agree than you should use URL encode (as a general principal for anything you add as a query parameter to the URL). But there's no specific need to URL encode `/` in the query string since they have no special meaning in that part of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't require files from user input without validation!**

```
<?php
// For Security a list of granted paths.
$allowedPaths = [
    'folder/dashboard.php',
];

$main = isset($_GET['main']) ? $_GET['main'] : '';
if(!in_array($main, $allowedPaths) {
   // Error handling
   die('Path not allowed');
}

require $main;
?>
```

The link could look like

```
<a href="?main=folder%2Fdashboard.php">
```

- Note, that the URL **values** must be encoded -> `echo urlencode('folder/dashboard.php');` to make the slash valid.
- Note to not add `.php` extension twice (once in URL and again in code).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As per @Magnus Eriksson's comment: "in general, there's no need to URL encode / in the query string since they have no special meaning in that part of the URL" I tried it without encoding and it worked fine. So, the double .php seemed to be the issue. On the other hand, the part about validation is highly appreciated. I will certainly implement it.

Comment: _"Note, that the URL values must be encoded ... to make the slash valid."_ - Not true. Slashes has no special meaning in the query string. The server only uses the part before the `?` as a path.

Comment: It is just because of the genius error handling of the browser. But in general URL values need to be URL encoded. **Just because it works, does not say it is correct.**